# Learing laravel and have problem with getURLList();

Tags: php, laravel, function

Im trying to learn Laravel framework and having trouble with getURLList();

In the tutorial that im following it says.

```
class StudInsertController extends Controller
{
    
    public function insert(){
        $urlData = getURLList();
        return view('stud_create');
    }
```

But the getURLLIST(); comes back as

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\getURLList()`

And i dont find any information about that.
Is it because the tutorial is for older version of Laravel?

The link to the tutorial itself is here:

https://www.studentstutorial.com/laravel/insert-data-laravel

Can somebody point me in the right direction.

Comment: There's no helper method called getURLList() in laravel, please check if the source code of this tutorial contains custom helper file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

From what the tutorials says, there are just a few files that you need to touch which effectly means they are not adding a custom helper method.

After looking at the code, I don't see any use for the line of code getting the URLs. It would have been useful if you were to pass the data forward to your view.

So I would recommend you remove the line `$urlData = getURLList();`. It should work just fine. I don't know if the author left it there by error.